# How can i use FORMAT and CONCAT_WS togother

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**This is my Query**

```
declare @date datetime = getdate() 
declare @day int = day (@date) 
declare @month int = month (@date)
declare @year int = year (@date)
select format, CONCAT_WS('/', 'D', 'fr_Fr', @day,@month,@year) as [date du jour]
```

**how Can i use two function togther ?(FORMAT, CONCAT_WS) **

Comment: If you already have a `DateTime`, why bother deconstructing and reconstructing it again? Just use `format` on the date and that's it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `datefromparts()` :

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEFROMPARTS(@year, @month, @day), 'D', 'fr_Fr')
```

EDIT : It seems you want only `format()` :

```
SELECT FORMAT(@date, 'D', 'fr_Fr')
```

Comment: @badiszakaria, it's good that you found a useful answer. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left. It rewards the person who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too.